# Jenkins and JFrog Artifactory - how to set how many last builds should be stored?

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

I am uploading zip packages from Jenkins to Artifactory using the Artifactory Plugin.

I am using the following Upload step and it works, my only question is it possible to somehow configure how many last builds will be kept in Artifactory? (e.g. last 50 builds)

```
    stage ('Upload stage') {
        steps {
            rtUpload (
                serverId: 'Artifactory',
                spec: '''{
                      "files": [
                        {
                          "pattern": "package-*.zip",
                          "target": "artifactory/jenkins/"
                        }
                     ]
                }''',
            )
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure build retention during the publish build info step:

```java
stage ('Set build retention') {
    steps {
        rtBuildInfo (
            maxBuilds: 50
        )
    }
}

stage ('Upload stage') {
    steps {
        rtUpload (
            serverId: 'Artifactory',
            spec: '''{
                  "files": [
                    {
                      "pattern": "package-*.zip",
                      "target": "artifactory/jenkins/"
                    }
                 ]
            }'''
        )
    }
}

stage ('Publish build info') {
    steps {
        rtPublishBuildInfo (
            serverId: 'Artifactory'
        )
    }
}
```

For more information see [Triggering Build Retention](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Declarative+Pipeline+Syntax#DeclarativePipelineSyntax-TriggeringBuildRetention) documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot  @yahavi for your kind and prompt answer!!! I will try on this.
So basically if I have 50 maxBuilds and I trigger 51 build my 1st build will be automatically deleted, correct?

Comment: @AndreyDonald right

Comment: this is not correct because `maxBuilds` does not exist in `rtPublishBuildInfo` but in `rtBuildInfo`. So I added both of them - Publish with serverID and BuildInfo with maxBuilds. Can you give me the correct order for rtBuildInfo, rtPublishBuildInfo and rtUpload? Thanks

Comment: @AndreyDonald you are right, I'm sorry. I edited my answer.

Comment: rtPublishBuildInfo can/should be after the rtUpload or it should be before it? thanks for your update! Also could be maybe so kind to assist me with this further issue I am having? If you had similar experience... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70064241/jenkins-how-to-ftp-folder-file-from-linux-agent-towards-the-windows-server Thanks!

Comment: `rtPublishBuildInfo` should be after `rtUpload`. Basically, it should be at the end of the job.